# Cloudera Manager: Where do I put Java ClassPath for MapReduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, lzo

I've got Hadoop-Lzo working happily on my local pseudo-cluster but the second I try the same jar file in production, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native-lzo library not available
```

The libraries are verified to be on the DataNodes, so my question is:

In what screen / setting do I specify the location of the native-lzo library?

Answer (score 3):

For MapReduce you need to add the entries to the MapReduce Client Environment Safety valve. You can find **MapReduce Client Safety** by going to **View and Edit** tab under **Configuration**. Then add these lines over there :

- HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/HADOOP_LZO/lib/hadoop/lib/*
- JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/HADOOP_LZO/lib/hadoop/lib/native

Also add the LZO codecs to the io.compression.codecs property under the MapReduce Service. To do that go to **io.compression** under **View and Edit** tab under **Configuration** and these lines :

- com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec
- com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec

Do not forget to restart your MR daemons after making the changes. Once restarted redeploy your MR client configuration.

For a detailed help on how to use LZO you can visit this link :
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_LZO_Compression.html

HTH

Comment: Still getting the RuntimeException. I've deployed the client configuration, restarted mapreduce service. Could there be anything else?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install lzop` in your TaskTracker nodes.